# Error de sintaxis del IDE arduino

Tags: arduino, sintaxis, ide, esp32

Saludo cordial.

Estoy trabajando con un ESP32 en el entorno del Arduino IDE. Nunca había tenido problemas trabajando allí, pero hoy se me presentó uno.

El tema es que cuando trato de subir mi código a la placa, surge el problema "exit code 1, acceso denegado". Lo que hice fue ejecutar el IDE como administrador, pero entonces me da un error de sintaxis. Mirando el error, creo que este se encuentra en una línea que dice lo siguiente:

```
cmd /c type nul > "C:\\Users\\JOSE" "DAVID\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\42C0FA6AF8BD933682804F1041E3204B/file_opts"
```

Creo que el error está en las comillas (" ") que hacen el espacio de mi nombre de usuario.

Entonces, mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma de editar este comando para corregirle eso?
Repito, esa línea es escrita y ejecutada por el IDE.

Agradezco su colaboración.
¡Gracias!

[image: Aqui esta todo el mensaje desde que inicia la compilacion hasta que falla]